# Как сделать предпросмотр ссылки при её добавлении на сайт через форму (как в Telegram)

Tags: html, site

Допустим, я добавляю ссылку через поле ввода и хочу чтобы эта ссылка преобразовалась в превью и краткое описание того сайта на который она ведёт, как например в том же телеграме. Перекопав половину интернета, я не нашёл нормального решения с примерами кода на js, css и html.

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема? Задайте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на одной проблеме. Возникла сложность с отображением превью, получением данных или что-то еще? Добавьте детали в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1456490/edit).

Answer (score 1):

- На самом сайте эта информация предоставляется с помощью meta тегов [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/)
- Для их парсинга можно использовать [metadata-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metadata-scraper?activeTab=readme)

```js
const getMetaData = require('metadata-scraper');
const url = 'https://github.com/BetaHuhn/metadata-scraper';
getMetaData(url).then((data) => {
    console.log(data['title']);
    console.log(data['description']);
    console.log(data['image']);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но есть ли более простые варианты парсинга, допустим через скрипты jq или ещё как?

Comment: @Andrey1991, что Вы имеете ввиду под "jq скриптами"?